# Issue regarding collapsible navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using bootstrap navbar and I have a collapsible navbar. But I am facing a strange problem, whenever I am going to open my site on small devices i.e mobile phone or tablet (actually for which devices I need the collapsible navbar), it is by default opening the navbar. This should not happen. If I click on the navbar button (three line button) then only the navbar should expand. But my navbar is expanding first time by default on small devices.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header"><%= image_tag("logo.png", alt: "industryPrime") %></div>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="myNavbar">
 <ul class="navigation pull-right">
 <li class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown">
<button id="feature_button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="background-color: transparent; color: #51a3af; border: none; font-size:11px;">FEATURES
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="paperless_purchase_section">Paperless purchase</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="efficient_stores_section">Efficient stores</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="peace_of_mind_section">Peace of mind</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </li>

      <li>

        <%= link_to "Case Study", user_maan_case_study_path %>
      </li>

      <li class="req_demo">

        <%= link_to "Request Demo", user_request_demo_page_path , :onclick => "demo_clicked()" ,:onmouseover => "start_count()" , :onmouseout => "stop_count()" %>
      </li>



        <li id="Login button section"><%= link_to 'Login', {controller: 'sessions', action: 'new'} %></li>



        <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><%= image_tag("contact_us.png") %>+91 98302-15353</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

My website link is http://www.industryprime.com

please help me to fix it.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove class `in` in  `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="myNavbar">` . Hope it will help you.

Comment: Most Welcome :)